# selectize.js typeahead character (yellow) color is not resetting

Tags: jquery, selectize.js

I tried using the selectize.js for one of my component and i am facing an issue. Can someone help in pointing what is wrong?

[image]

I just typed first few character of all the option and remove those character, but the yellow highlight is not resetting from previous type. The appended span to the div with option class tag is not removed.

**JSP**

```
<select id="select-state" multiple>
    <option>Mustard</option>
    <option>Ketchup</option>
    <option>Relish</option>
</select>
```

**script**

```
<script>
    $(function() {
        $('#select-state').selectize({
            plugins: ['remove_button'],
        });
    });
</script>
```

Version i am using for selectize.js is 0.12.3.

https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/selectize.js/0.12.3/css/selectize.bootstrap2.min.css

https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/selectize.js/0.12.3/js/standalone/selectize.min.js

**jsfiddle:**
http://jsfiddle.net/wh6Nx/308/

**Update**

As the issue which i mentioned has already be added part of 0.12.4 milestone. May be future release won't have this issue.

Comment: can you provide a jsfiddle or plunkr example?

Comment: Trying it in [Codepen](http://codepen.io/Bes7weB/pen/jraokW?editors=1111), I've had this error in console : «Selectize: Dependency MicroPlugin is missing». Didn't find a cdn for it... It looks like a dependency of Selectize.js that you have to download : https://www.npmjs.com/package/microplugin

Comment: @n0m4d : First of all big sorry! i pasted wrong js link above. I have edited that url and also added jsfiddle link.

Comment: Is @smcd's answer good for you? It looks like your answer...

Comment: @LouysPatriceBessette - No still i am seeing issue in that jsfiddle which he provided. https://jsfiddle.net/kthy1gtx/1/

Comment: Hew... Strange, because the yellow highlight seems to behave correctly in this Fiddle. Browser issue ? Ok here in Chrome. I notice that the blue for "option selected" remains... But the yellow is ok.

Comment: @LouysPatriceBessette - I tried this fiddle in all my browser's but still i am seeing the issue. Blue one we can control with highlight property (by setting false). But yellow is the one i need to get ride when we hit backspace after selecting.

Comment: All the browsers I have available on my PC work out OK with clearing the highlighting. It is a hackish method to remove the highlighting though... Have you tried other select enhancement options? I've used [select2](https://select2.github.io/) and had minimal trouble (3.5 series, haven't tried 4.x) and there's [chosen](https://github.com/harvesthq/chosen) too, seems popular

Comment: @smcd - I had look into select2 as well, but the selected option remains in dropdown even after selection. So for me that has to remove as that option got selected and restore on removing that option.

Answer (score 2):

Here's a link to a bug report that looks like the issue you are experiencing https://github.com/selectize/selectize.js/issues/1141

Here's a fiddle demonstrating issue https://jsfiddle.net/kthy1gtx/

Here's a hack to work around the issue

https://jsfiddle.net/kthy1gtx/1/

```
$(function() {
    $('#select-state').selectize({
        plugins: ['remove_button'],
        onType: function(val) {
            if (val === "") { /* when the input is cleared, clear all cache highlighting */
                $.each(this.renderCache.option, function(k, v) {
                    v.innerHTML = $(v).text();
                });
            }
        }
    });
});
```

Only works on typing, select with mouse and cut or delete still has issue.

Comment: Still i see that issue with jsFiddle you provided above with fix.

Comment: The https://jsfiddle.net/kthy1gtx/1/ fiddle clears search highlighting for me Firefox 49.0.1, Chromium 53.0.2785.89, IE11, and Edge browsers on Windows 10 PC

Comment: Steps used to reproduce the issue:

Type Mus,  
press enter,  
press backspace,  

Type Ket,  
press enter,  
press backspace,  

Type Re,  
press enter,  
press backspace,  


Expand dropdown to see yellow highlight

Comment: @Mohan:  I suggest you hit the «new issue» green button on [GitHub](https://github.com/selectize/selectize.js/issues/1141) and give this usefull «how to reproduce» sequence with a link to this actual SO Question. Stack Overflow is not intended to debug all existing plugins. It's a Q/A site. You have your answer... -This is a plugin bug-.

Comment: @LouysPatriceBessette - Sure will do it. And mean while as smcd suggest i tried using select2 with few custom script to achieve my need. Thanks to all for your kind input.

Comment: Hopefully you can get it worked out! I didn't test hitting enter earlier after typing characters, only typing then backspacing. Whoops :)